# arraylist keeps updating its content

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

what I understand is that 'Arraylists' are a reference to a certain address in the memory so to stop overriding it.we need to create new one and that is what I did

so basicly i am trying to load some data from file and compare the loaded line with existing data,if exist it will be added to "temp_super" then a new "NonPlayableFighter" will be created with "temp_super"

i also tried to get

```
temp_super = new ArrayList<SuperAttack>();
```

out but same problem

```
ArrayList<x-men>  strongFoes= new ArrayList<x-men>();
ArrayList<SuperAttack>  temp_super = null;  
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line = "";
        int position = 1;
        NonPlayableFighter non;


        int k=0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {

            line.replace("\\s", "");
            String[] array = line.split(",");

                    temp_super = new ArrayList<SuperAttack>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < superattack.size(); j++)
                        {
                            if (array[i]
                                    .equals(superattack.get(j).getName()))
                            {
                                temp_super.add(superattack.get(j));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
               if(k==1)
                 System.out.print(strongFoes.get(0)
                                    .getSuperAttacks().get(0).getName());
//i have checked till here and the first non is still have old data
           non = new NonPlayableFighter(name, level, maxhealth,
                            blastdamage, physicaldamage, maxki, maxstamina,
                            strong, temp_super, temp_ultimate);
           strongFoes.add(non);
            k++
```

...... but what I get is always the last "temp_super" in the whole "strongFoes" 
just before the non = new(...) tha expected data is there
after it data is replaced with new one i dont know why
why is it then ?

Comment: Move the `temp_super = new ...` outside the conditional (and remove the unnecessary `clear()` call).

Comment: didn`t solve the problem

Comment: Which temp super do you expect to have? You are reassigning it to a new ArrayList, of course it will be the last one.

Comment: i expect each line to create me temp_super and i will use it in "non"
..then the next line create another one for not to update the same one
and i use it to create another "non" ...the first "non"have the same result as other"non"

Comment: check the question again :)

Comment: You set position to 1, then you increment it to 2. Then you never reassign the arraylist again. They all should have the same arraylist.

Comment: there is a reset position in the end of the while loop

Comment: You keep changing your question again and again. Is there some `Debug My Code` contest going on?

Comment: no its just my code is 1600 line so its not easy to bring 20 line out of it..and yes my debug shows that what causing the problem is these lines

Comment: Move the `List<SuperAttack> temp_super = new ArrayList<SuperAttack>();` to outside of the if conditional, and remove the declaration where you assign it to null.

Comment: no still the same problem

Comment: Can you update your post with the current version of the code then. How do you check that the lists are the same?

Comment: @matt i edited the code + checking code...so for sure the problem not in temp_super...its in "non"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are only initializing the `super_temp` ArrayList once when `position == 1`

```
if (position == 1)
{
    temp_super = new ArrayList<SuperAttack>();
    temp_super.clear();
    ...
```

But then you increment the position by doing `position++` and all subsequent `non = new NonPlayableFighter(...)` calls have the same object of `temp_super`.

Comment: i do so because position ==1 is the only place where temp_super get value
other positions for anothers tasks

Comment: You should move `non = new NonPlayableFighter(...)` insde the `if` condition then. Otherwise, it keeps on adding the same object.

Comment: why is that? 
i get only one "non" in each line so the other if conditions bring rest of info. to it thats all

Comment: You have everything inside `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)`. You want to process everything for each line you read?

Comment: ok the point is that each 3 lines of file represent one "non" so position is basicaly increment with each read then in position 3 it reset to 1 to repeat the whole process.....for the variables all of them are reinitialized again in each if condition that represent them .....and super_temp get changed already but after creating the "non" i found out that all other "non" changed too...which by logic means that i am not initializing temp_super to a new one....but i do